# Geofencing to display all offices in 5km radius

Tags: android, gps, maps, geofencing

I want to display all my client's offices in 5kms radius from a location. The office addresses are stored in the db as latitude and longitude. I have the current location of the user. I'm clueless on how to get all the latitudes and longitudes inside the 5kms circle to send to the server or is there a better approach ? 
The client application is an android device.

Answer (score 0):

You need to investigate the use of the [Haversine Formula](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) which calculates the distance between two points on a sphere. Depending on your database you maybe able to plug in the latitudes and longitudes directly with an SQL statement or alternatively exclude all entries outside of a bounding box, and then iterate through the remaining entries.

So if you can calculate the point 5km east and 5km west you know any relevant locations must have a longitude between these values. Repeat with north and south.

The links at the bottom of the Wikipedia page include implementations in most programming languages.